# Is there way that i can pass role for user in user registration , i'm currently passing a list of strings and it's working is postman but not in front

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, api, authentication

So i'm trying to add role to my user when i create a new one but it doesn't seem to work , i don't understand the reason.

> This is my model for user

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String first_name;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String last_name;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String profession;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    
    public User(){
        
    }
    public User(String username,String first_name, String last_name, String profession,String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", first_name=" + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", profession="
                + profession + ", username=" + username + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", roles="
                + roles + "]";
    }

}
```

> This is my controller

```
//Register user
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signupRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signupRequest.getUsername())) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
    }
    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signupRequest.getEmail())) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
    }
    
    User user = new User(
            signupRequest.getUsername(),
            signupRequest.getFirst_name(),
            signupRequest.getLast_name(),
            signupRequest.getProfession(),
            signupRequest.getEmail(),
            encoder.encode(signupRequest.getPassword())
            );
    
    Set<String> strRoles = signupRequest.getRole();
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    if (strRoles == null) {
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERoles.ROLE_ADMIN)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
        roles.add(userRole);
    } else {
        strRoles.forEach(role -> {
            switch (role) {
            case "manager":
                Role hrManagerRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERoles.ROLE_HR_MANAGER)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(hrManagerRole);
                break;
            case "user":
                Role hrAgent = roleRepository.findByName(ERoles.ROLE_HR_AGENT)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(hrAgent);
                break;
            case "technical":
                Role techInterviewer = roleRepository.findByName(ERoles.ROLE_TECHNICAL_INTERVIEWER)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(techInterviewer);
                break;
            
            }
        });
    }
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
}
```

> this is my signup reqeust page

```
@NotBlank
  @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
  private String username;
  
  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 6, max = 35)
  private String first_name;
  
  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 4, max = 20)
  private String last_name;
  
  @NotBlank
  @Size(min =10, max = 50)
  private String profession;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 50)
  @Email
  private String email;

  private Set<String> role;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 6, max = 40)
  private String password;
  
  public SignUpRequest(){
      
  }

  public SignUpRequest(@NotBlank @Size(min = 3, max = 20) String username,
        @NotBlank @Size(min = 6, max = 35) String first_name, @NotBlank @Size(min = 4, max = 20) String last_name,
        @NotBlank @Size(min = 10, max = 50) String profession, @NotBlank @Size(max = 50) @Email String email,
        @NotBlank @Size(min = 6, max = 40) String password) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.profession = profession;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }


public Set<String> getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Set<String> role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SignUpRequest [username=" + username + ", first_name=" + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name
            + ", profession=" + profession + ", email=" + email + ", role=" + role + ", password=" + password + "]";
}
```

> This is my model in angular

```
    export class User {
    id? : any;
    first_name? : string;
    last_name? : string;
    profession? : string;
    username? : string;
    email? : string;
    password? : string;
    roles? : string[];
}
```

> this is my register method

```
    onSubmit(){
    const {username , first_name , last_name , profession , email , password , roles} = this.form;
    const userData : SignUpData = {username , first_name , last_name , profession , email , password , roles : [roles]};
    this.authSerivce.register_user(userData).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.isSuccessful = true;
        this.isSignedUpFailed = false;
        console.log(userData)
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isSignedUpFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }
```

> this is my role input in html

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label for="roles">Role</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="roles"
            [(ngModel)]="form.roles"
            required
            #roles="ngModel"
          />

        </div>
```

> this my service class

```
 import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from 'app/models/user.model';

const AUTH_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

export interface SignUpData {
  username: string;
  first_name : string;
  last_name : string;
  profession : string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  roles: string[];
}



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
user : User;

  
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  //Login service for user authentication , sends data inside observable through the AUTH_API/signin and if it matches existing user , authenticates
  login_user(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signin', {
      username,
      password
    }, httpOptions);
  }


  //Signup service for user account creation , sends data inside observable throught the AUTH_API/signup and if data is valid , creates account
  register_user(user : SignUpData) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup',user,httpOptions);
  }


}
```

> This is the payload after i submit my form

```
 {username: "aziza", first_name: "aziza", last_name: "chouchane", profession: 
 "student",…}
email: "aziza@gmail.com"
first_name: "aziza"
last_name: "chouchane"
password: "poiuraze"
profession: "student"
roles: ["user"]
0: "user"
username: "aziza"
```

Comment: role vs roleS my friend. you did a typo misstake on your SignUpRequest object

Comment: do you mean that i need to change   private Set<String> role to    private Set<String> roles ?

Comment: yes of course. Look at your payload, its "roles"

Comment: Let me explain more what my problem is , i could pass the role as an array of string , but somehow the server reads my input as null and assign the role admin directly , even though i put in user which means according to my controller it's the hr agent role , that is what i'm stuck at.

Comment: I tried changing to roles still not working , always assigning ADMIN role

Comment: have you as well renamed your accessors ? getRoles setRoles ? (mapping between payload and java object is made thanks to the accessors by reflection)

Comment: Thank you very much stephane you saved me a lot of time , i changed it in getters and setters and it worked , i never realized this was this sensitive , thanks for your time ! :D

Comment: tip : when you rename a field, do it with the 'REFACTORING' functionality of your IDE, and choose to include accessors ;)